# wrap loose string in class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have content that is automatically generated by the software I am using and I need to wrap the loose string in a class so that I can style it.

```js
$('label.ng-binding').wrapInner('<div class="rpc_cb"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="ng-binding">
  <input class="checking" 
         ng-model="model[options.key]" 
         id="formly_1_checkbox_email-accepts_email_8" 
         name="email.accepts_email" 
         formly-custom-validation="" 
         type="checkbox">
  Yes, I would like to receive email from this site.
</label>
```

WrapInner will wrap all of the content but I need to target "Yes, I would like to receive email from this site."

Thank you!

Comment: what about .wrapInner() ?

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant, I tried wrappInner, this will wrap the input and the text into one when I only need the text wrapped

Comment: To "target" the Yes... text, I suggest putting that text inside of <span> tags with a unique ID value. Currently, this text and the checkbox input element are all inside the <label> tags.

Comment: why not to use angular as tag.

Comment: I do not have access to the html, I am not able to edit the html to add span tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('label.ng-binding')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    })
  .wrap( '<div class="rpc_cb"></div>' );
```

```css
.rpc_cb{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="ng-binding"><input class="checking" ng-model="model[options.key]" id="formly_1_checkbox_email-accepts_email_8" name="email.accepts_email" formly-custom-validation="" type="checkbox">
  Yes, I would like to receive email from this site.
  </label>
```

Try this, and set class. Then you can style it.